# How to run diskpart commands from within node using child_process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Goal: Run diskpart commands and read responses from within the node environment.
The code so far only console.log the "dir" command. How do I manage to go into diskpart before running the other diskpart commands like "list disk"?

Problem: Can't find a way to get into diskpart and thereafter being able to run other diskpart commands.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var cmd = "dir";
exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error running diskpart list command");
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("stdout data");
  console.log(stdout);

  console.log("stderr data");
  console.log(stderr);
});
```

Sample output:

```
2021-06-22  20:20    <DIR>          .
2021-06-22  20:20    <DIR>          ..
2021-06-18  00:11                12 .gitignore
2021-06-19  22:39               508 config.txt
2021-06-19  22:40             2�314 init.js
2021-06-22  20:09    <DIR>          node_modules
2021-06-22  20:09            24�899 package-lock.json
2021-06-22  20:09               354 package.json
2021-06-22  20:25               137 test.js
2021-06-22  20:25               334 test2.js
               7 File(s)         28�558 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   3�877�974�016 bytes free
```

Comment: Can you share error message ?

Comment: I receive no error.

Comment: You could chain the commands with pipes or `&&` if you only want to use command line  programs. Or you could perform the  [directory work in JS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and then `exec` for the diskpart